# Deploy node.js express backend to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku

Its my first time deploying on heroku and i keep getting errors, the build is succeeding but when the build finishes and i try to view the API response in the browser via heroku i get back an error of - 
 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
 
logs from heroku -
2021-12-11T19:16:54.702260+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-12-11T19:16:54.708322+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! example-create-react-app-express@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
2021-12-11T19:16:54.708419+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-12-11T19:16:54.708524+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-12-11T19:16:54.708602+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the example-create-react-app-express@1.0.0 start script.
2021-12-11T19:16:54.708721+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-12-11T19:16:54.718471+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-12-11T19:16:54.719294+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-12-11T19:16:54.719298+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-12-11T19_16_54_709Z-debug.log
2021-12-11T19:16:54.908600+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-12-11T19:16:55.067169+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-12-11T19:16:56.373561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/api/hello" host=agile-spire-07157.herokuapp.com request_id=ab0c71fb-1be1-4829-b123-e57cc4e7fafd fwd="67.177.196.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-12-11T19:17:56.820732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=agile-spire-07157.herokuapp.com request_id=b9615ee7-190d-44ce-8d97-c099d26149ca fwd="67.177.196.118" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Any help at all is greatly appreciated

Folder structure:

[image]

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/build/index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const apiKey = process.env.APIKEY

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
    const { term, location } = req.query
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}`,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
        }
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            return JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)
        })
        .then(function (jsonResponse) {
            res.send(jsonResponse)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

package.json for server:

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "cd ../client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i think i figured it out, it seems to be working and heres what i changed:
I added a Procfile in the root directory (make sure its a capital P) and added this to it -> web: node server.js 
(so just put web: node(whatever your server file is named)
If you are storing your API key in a .env file then you have to let heroku know youre doing just that. You can let heroku know this by typing this command in terminal while in server folder 
heroku config:set <key=value> 
 If you did this right youll get back a response from heroku saying just that. 
 This is a link i followed instructions with that worked for me 
https://dzone.com/articles/deploy-your-node-express-app-on-heroku-in-8-easy-s

Final server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const port = process.env.PORT || 2000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const apiKey = process.env.APIKEY

app.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
    const { term, location } = req.query
    const config = {
        method: 'get',
        url: `https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?term=${term}&location=${location}`,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${apiKey}`
        }
    };

    axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            return JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)
        })
        .then(function (jsonResponse) {
            res.send(jsonResponse)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 2000, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`))
```

Package.json for server:

```
{
  "name": "example-create-react-app-express",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.17.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "client": "cd ../client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```